# perl using bless self in script and PerlCritic

Tags: perl, oop, perl-critic, bless

I am used to using `$self` for OO Perl even when I am just writing self-contained scripts without naming my package at all. For example, my `script.pl` would start like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $self = bless {};
$self->time_stamp(localtime(time()));
1;

sub time_stamp {
  my ($self,@args) = @_;
  # Getter/setter
  my $ftime_stamp;
  if( 1 < scalar @args ) {
    $ftime_stamp = strftime "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", @args;
    $self->{'time_stamp'} = $ftime_stamp;
  }
  return $self->{'time_stamp'};
}
[...]
```

These scripts sometimes turn into proper modules, but some times I just let them be as such.

This though goes against Perl Critic of "One-argument blesses":

```
One-argument "bless" used at line 162, column 12.  See page 365 of PBP.  Severity: 5
```

Is there a clean way of naming my bless but still having everything contained in my `script.pl`?

Comment: You have to bless variable into class/package ([bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) second parameter). Into which package you want to bless it?

Comment: `perldoc -f bless`: "If CLASSNAME is omitted, the current package is used."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not everything criticized by perlcritic *has* to be fixed. But usually, it really is preferable to specify the package name for `bless`.

If you don't declare a package name, your code implicitly is in `package main`. If you don't care about the actual name and want to refer to the current package, use the `__PACKAGE__` symbol, e.g.:

```
my $self = bless {} => __PACKAGE__;
```

You could also write a little bit of boilerplate:

```
sub new {
  my ($class) = @_;
  return bless {} => $class;
}

my $self = __PACKAGE__->new;
```

Or you could use an object system like `Moo`:

```
use Moo;
has _time_stamp => (is => 'rw');

sub time_stamp {
  my ($self, @args) = @_;
  if( 1 < scalar @args ) {
    $self->_time_stamp(strftime "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", @args);
  }
  return $self->_time_stamp;
}

my $self = __PACKAGE__->new;  # a "new" is autogenerated
```

Comment: I tried your __PACKAGE__ solution and it works nicely. I think this will do for me at the moment. It is just annoying not having a clean sheet in perlcritic, and I really want to go up from stern to harsh to cruel up to brutal!

Comment: It seems morally wrong to bless into `main::`? `perl -MData::Dumper -we'sub foo{\@_} print Dumper bless({1,2})->foo(7)'`

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own Perl Critic policy and configure critic to use that instead of default. `Perl::Critic::Policy::ClassHierarchies::ProhibitOneArgBless` is the rule you want to disable. If you want that rule in most cases, however, you can use `##no critic` marker in your source to disable critic for that particular line.

See [perlcritic documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.121/lib/Perl/Critic.pm#CONFIGURATION).